# vector calculus question: finding equation of surface tangential to plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces

The height of a surface above ground level is given by $$z(x,y)=e^{6-(x^2+2y^2)}$$
where x and y are the horizontal distances going east and north respectively.

a) A small ball is placed on the surface at the point $x=2$,$y=1$ and is released from rest. in which direction ( in the horizontal plane) will it begin to roll? 
    (Give your answer as a compass bearing)

b) An ant is placed on the surface at $x=2$, $y=1$. give the compass bearing it should follow, initially, in order to follow a level path.

c) Find the equation of the plane tangential to the surface at $x=2$ , $y=1$, in the form, $ax+by+cz=d$

Attempt a) my thought process for this was to apply the $\nabla$ operator on $z(x,y)$ as follows:
 $$\nabla z=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\textbf{i}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\textbf{j}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial z}\textbf{k}$$

$$=-2xe^{6-(x^2+2y^2)}\textbf{i}-4ye^{6-(x^2+2y^2)}\textbf{j}$$

Then at the point $y=1$, $x=2$

$$\nabla z=-2(2)e^{6-((2)^2+2(1)^2)}\textbf{i}-4(1)e^{6-((2)^2+2(1)^2)}\textbf{j}$$

$$\nabla z=-4\textbf{i}-4\textbf{j}$$
Hence the small ball will be moving south-west at compass bearing of $225°$.

I just wanted clarification if my attempt at a) is correct and was confused as to how to approach b) and c), thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats fine, although in your expression for $\nabla z$ there should be no term $\frac{\partial z}{\partial z}$ (What would that even mean?)

A very useful property of the gradient vector is that if you move in the horizontal plane by small distances $dx,dy$, then the vertical movement is the inner product of the gradient vector with the vector $(dx,dy)$, ie
$$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} dy$$

and your mouse wants to make dz=0. As for the plane, let it be given by $$z=ax+by+c$$ and you want to choose $a,b,c$ so that at the place concerned, this plane has the same gradient and the same elevation as the given surface.

Comment: im not really sure what you mean for part b), in terms of figuring it out, or for part c)

Comment: another concern i had was that on my solution for a), does $/nabla z$ give you the greatest increase of the height? so if i wanted the rate of decrese my compass bearing would be  north-east and not south-west?

Comment: @odesnit Well,I was trying not to do the whole thing for you, but to give information that would make you see it the right way......

Comment: @odesnit Well,I was trying not to do the whole thing for you, but to give information that would make you see it in the right way......

But the gradient vector is usually defined as $$(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},\frac{\partial_z}{\partial y})$$ and this could point either uphill or downhill. Certainly a sign convention is needed, but bringing in uphill/downhill causes more trouble than it cures.The gradient vector could be $(0,0)$. In general it maximizes the rate of change without saying if the change is positive or negative.

Comment: But if you move in the direction $(\xi\eta)$ then the sign of $x\xi+y\eta$ tells you up or down.

Comment: i think i understand what you mean for b), to get it to follow a level path, the product of the gradient vector and the proposed new vector should be zero so an appropriate path to take would be one perpendicular to the gradient vector

Comment: so for example -4i+4j

Comment: Your first comment, yes. Imagine hiking on a hill.To stay level, you move at a right angle to the direction that takes you most steeply downhill (or uphill)

Im not sure what you are getting at in your second comment.

Comment: what i meant was that the compass bearing it should follow is north-west as the it is at right angles to south west?

Comment: Ah, at that specific point, yes

Comment: im still a little unsure how to start part c currently

Comment: Consider the plane $z=ax+by+c=0$. What is it's gradient vector? At the location (2,1) this plane must have the same gradient vector and the same
height as the given function.

Comment: Concerning a), since the gradient points in the sense of greatest increase of the function, the ball should roll down in the oposite sense, so in the $4\textbf{i}+4\textbf{j}$ direction, north-east

Comment: hey zamu thanks for that, that would mean for b) a compass bearing it should follow to follow a level path would be south-east.